# Hello ive read about 10 tutorials, but i keep getting errors all the time,this is my Makefile file and errors

Tags: c++, list, linked-list, makefile

LNode : Linked List Node

LList : Linked List

Eleman : Linked Lists value type

Kontrol : All main codes

Program : main , contains kontrol()

```
g++ -I "./include" -c ./src/Program.cpp -o ./lib/Program.o
g++ ./lib/LNode.o ./lib/LListe.o ./lib/Kontrol.o ./lib/Program.o ./lib/Eleman.o -o ./bin/program
./lib/Kontrol.o:Kontrol.cpp:(.text+0x3e): undefined reference to `LListe<Eleman>::LListe()'
./lib/Kontrol.o:Kontrol.cpp:(.text+0x1ad): undefined reference to `LListe<Eleman>::pushBack(Eleman 
const&)'
./lib/Kontrol.o:Kontrol.cpp:(.text+0x1de): undefined reference to `LListe<Eleman>::end()'
./lib/Kontrol.o:Kontrol.cpp:(.text+0x2fc): undefined reference to `LListe<Eleman>::pushBack(Eleman 
const&)'
./lib/Kontrol.o:Kontrol.cpp:(.text+0x3fa): undefined reference to `LListe<Eleman>::pushBack(Eleman 
const&)'
./lib/Kontrol.o:Kontrol.cpp:(.text+0x44e): undefined reference to `LListe<Eleman>::end()'
./lib/Kontrol.o:Kontrol.cpp:(.text+0x587): undefined reference to `LListe<Eleman>::pushBack(Eleman 
const&)'
./lib/Kontrol.o:Kontrol.cpp:(.text+0x68e): undefined reference to `LListe<Eleman>::pushBack(Eleman 
const&)'
./lib/Kontrol.o:Kontrol.cpp:(.text+0x711): undefined reference to `LListe<Eleman>::begin()'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile:3: recipe for target 'program' failed
mingw32-make: *** [program] Error 1
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? You need to give more details about your purpose, and edit out the question to include your minimum reproducible code. See [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: There is no makefile or code here, which makes it hard to answer the question.